# как вывести информацию, которая находится в sqlite в приложение на xamarin

Tags: sqlite3, xamarin

Посмотрел много видео по данной теме, все делаю как на видео, но у меня не появляется информация с бд, есть appshell в котором все страницы и переходы, пытаюсь вывести на первой странице информацию[image: подключение к бд]

[image: Вывод]

отображение на странице

[image: на какой странице отображается]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)